# CanCan: How can I retrieve records with a conditional inner join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inner-join, cancan

I want to fetch records based on one of two sets of conditions.  A user can read public Time records (private == false) if they are a network member.  A user can read private Time records (private == true) if they are a network member and they are a participant the Time.  I have tried the following, but the inner join has preventing ORing the conditions:

```
can :read, Time, network: {memberships: {user_id: current_user.id}}, private: false
can :read, Time, network: {memberships: {user_id: current_user.id}}, private: true, participants: {id: current_user.id}
```

The other thing I need to do is narrow the records returned by the current network, but I can't see to get the nested ability definitions to work.  Any suggestions?